# ¿Se puede acceder a una cola privada de un servidor remoto MSMQ?

Tags: c#

buen dia,

tengo una aplicación la cual obtiene los mensajes que se configuran en una cola privada, quisiera saber si es posible poder acceder a esta cola privada desde otro servidor, mirando la documentación de Microsoft intente validar con el parámetro MachineName pero me genera la excepción `nombre de la ruta de acceso de la cola no valida.` agradezco su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sonaria raro que pudieras acceder a algo privado... por algo es privado no?

Comment: Mas que una pregunta de C# es de Infraestructura de Windows. Pero es valida desde el punto de vista de DEV no? El servicio de [MSMQ (Microsoft Messaging Queue) deben abrir los puertos en el firewall del server o cluster par que te puedas comunicar (aqui un post relacionado)](https://serverfault.com/questions/38260/msmq-firewall-ports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no te puedes conectar a la maquina remota para el servicio de Queue, supongo que utlizadas MSMQ (Microsoft Messaging Queue) o similar protocolo, es porque no tiene abierto los puertos para la conexion (o no tiene dicho servicio)

Deben abrir los puertos en el firewall del server o cluster par que te puedas comunicar

Por ejemplo, la respuest a en este post ["MSMQ works on TCP or UDP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861559/msmq-works-on-tcp-or-udp)

> This KB details which ports and protocols are used: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;178517
> The following ports are used for Microsoft Message Queuing operations: TCP: 1801 RPC: 135, 2101*, 2103*, 2105* UDP: 3527, 1801 The following is new for Message Queuing 3.0: While Message Queuing uses the same ports that are used in earlier versions of the product, Message Queuing also introduces TCP port 389. TCP port 389 has to be open for MQIS queries that are made directly against Active Directory. Additionally, Message Queuing 3.0 introduces HTTP Messaging that requires that the port that is specified for the Message Queuing virtual directory be open also.
> This information is useful for interpreting the following: Netstat -a output A network trace Configuring a firewall

Respuestas originales:

- [MSMQ Firewall Ports](https://serverfault.com/questions/38260/msmq-firewall-ports)
- ["MSMQ works on TCP or UDP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861559/msmq-works-on-tcp-or-udp)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Comment: Hola buen día, voy a validarlo muchas gracias